# Doubly Linked List - What is causing my code to throw a compiler error and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, doubly-linked-list

I've been working on a Doubly Linked List code and I'm unable to locate what is causing an error every time I attempt compiling. The error being thrown is

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   DoublyList::DoublyList(void)" (??0?$DoublyList@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function >_main
>   1>Doubly List.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

DoublyList.h -> http://pastebin.com/5wbeKksv 
DoublyListNode.h and main.cpp -> http://pastebin.com/vVdGpgaW

Comment: Note that this isn't a compiler error, but rather a linker error.

Answer (score 2):

You declare but don't define `DoublyList` default constructor. Same goes for its destructor.

Comment: Wow. It worked. Thanks. Such an embarrassing mistake. Would be awesome if the error was more user friendly like "You forgot to declare this".

Comment: @Falmung: It would be "You forgot to define this", you do declare it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a constructor for DoublyList but not defined it.  Add a {} after your DoublyList() and see if it works take off the ; too.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the copy constructor, but forgotten to define the default constructor:

```c++
template< class T >
DoublyList< T > :: DoublyList() : head(NULL), size( 0 )
{
    // empty body
} // end DoublyList
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question, and I know this isn't the codereview section, but here are some of my thoughts.

In your insert function

```
DoublyListNode < T > *newPtr = new DoublyListNode< T >(tempData);
newPtr->nextPtr = newPtr->prePtr = NULL;
if(newPtr == NULL)
{
     cout << "Insert cannot allocate memory\n";
} //end if
```

should be

```
DoublyListNode < T > *newPtr = new DoublyListNode< T >(tempData);
if(newPtr == NULL)
{
     cout << "Insert cannot allocate memory\n";
}else{
     newPtr->nextPtr = newPtr->prePtr = NULL;
     // rest of code
```

Also, in your find function

```
DoublyListNode< T > *currentPtr = head;
for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
{
     currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
} // end for
```

should be

```
DoublyListNode< T > *currentPtr = head;
for(int i = 1; currentPtr && (i < index); i++)
{
     currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
} // end for
```

Also, since you are using C++, consider making your indexes 0-based (looking at your code they are atm 1-based)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll be sure to apply it.